# How to change page title after navigation?

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I navigate from **First_Page** to another page **Second_Page** then user press on navigation bar back button and the application returns to the **First_Page** the title of **First_Page** stays with the **Second_Page** title and when I explicitly change it with `Title` attribute, it doesn't change, so what am I missing or what's is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Second_Page());
    Title ="First Page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of your code like this:

```
async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Title ="First Page";
      await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Second_Page());
}
```

If you first use `Navigation.PushAsync` ,the page title have not been changed.Only when `Navigation.PushAsync` finished then `Title` will be set .

So if you want first push page will see that `Title` will be set,you should set berfore push page.

Comment: Is it always not displayed correctly or for the first time?You can show some screenshots ,it will be helpful.

Comment: Yes it's always. actually it doesn't change in detail pages that when I navigate from one detail page to another one (when user select another option from the master page list). but it works (changes) when navigation is from one detail page to another page (not detail page) with my code (setting Title after navigation).